# Add button dynamically in current view

Tags: java, android

I did a qrcode reader but I need to add a Button .. How can I add an button programatically?
Example:

```
Button btnVoltar = new Button(this);
    btnVoltar.setText("Voltar");
    btnVoltar.setX(30);
    btnVoltar.setY(30);
```

but I need to add this button in view.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!isCameraAvailable()) {
        // Cancel request if there is no rear-facing camera.
        cancelRequest();
        return;
    }

    // Hide the window title.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mAutoFocusHandler = new Handler();

    // Create and configure the ImageScanner;
    setupScanner();

    // Create a RelativeLayout container that will hold a SurfaceView,
    // and set it as the content of our activity.

    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, this, autoFocusCB);
    setContentView(mPreview);
}
```

Comment: Get by id the layout you want to add your button in, and then use the addView(yourButton) function on this layout.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: But this activity hasn't xml file..how know I the layout id?

Comment: My bad, didn't noticed that. I think the best way to do this is to create an xml for your activity, with something like a SurfaceView for your CameraPreview, and your button or maybe try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13644740/2065418.

Comment: @DamienR. I did found in my example, where the surfaceview is added. Now can I add my button. I have tried: (but the button doesn't appear)    
  `mPreviewCallback = previewCallback;
        mAutoFocusCallback = autoFocusCb;
        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        
        Button btnVoltar = new Button(context);
        btnVoltar.setText("Voltar");
        btnVoltar.setX(30);
        btnVoltar.setY(30);
        
        addView(mSurfaceView);
        addView(btnVoltar);`